# Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable only at $0$ and at $\frac{1}{n}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

How to determine the existence of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is differentiable only at  $0$ and at $\frac{1}{n}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

It's more than enough to give an example but I have some difficulties with it.

Or even if it doesn't exist: how to find a hint that may be useful?

Comment: Does $f$ have to be continuous?

Comment: No, it may be any function on a real line. But it should satisfy the condition, described upwards.

Comment: If you have nowhere differentiable continuous function $f_1$ (which exists), then $f_2$, $f_2(x) = (x- a)f_1(x)$ is differentiable only in $x  = a$. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Partition $(0,1)$ into non-degenerate intervals $A_n$ with each $A_n$ centered at $1/n$. For each $n$ construct a function $f_n$ on $A_n$ that is differentiable only at $1/n$ and bounded in absolute value by $1$. "Paste them together" and call this function $g$. $g$ is almost what you want. To get non-differentiablity at $0$, multiply $g$ by $x^2$ (and define $g(0)=0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint to get started: define $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & x \text{ irrational}, \\ 0 & x \text{ rational}. \end{array} \right.$$

Then $x^2 f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ and nowhere else, $x^2(x-1)^2f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ and $1$ and nowhere else, $x^2(x-1)^2(x-1/2)^2 f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ and $1$ and $1/2$ and nowhere else, etc.

Can you pass from a finite number of points of differentiability to a sequence?

Comment: It's reasonable to contunie multiplication in order to get the function needed. So, this way we'll get something like $f(x)=x^{2} (x-1)^{2} (x-\frac{1}{2})^{2} \ldots (x-\frac{1}{n} ) \ldots  \cdot f(x) $.

Just the questuion is due to the number of terms: how many are they? Is it $\aleph$?

Comment: @Arteom How many roots does it have? If $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then there are a countable infinite number of roots, which means a countably infinte number of terms.

Comment: For $x \in (0,1)$ you will have $f(x) =0$, which is differentiable.

Comment: The infinite product $\Pi (x-1/n)^2$ seems to diverge to 0 for all $x\in (0,1)$. So your function seems to be identically 0. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

Let $$g(x)=\cases {\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\right) & if $0\le x \le 1$ , $x$ irrational \\
0 & elsewhere}$$

Then, in the interval $[0,1]$, $g(x)$ is only continuous and differentiable at $x=0$ and $x=1$ (and all the derivatives are zero).

The copy and paste the $y$-scaled/$x$-scaled-translated copies of it: $$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g(x \, n (n+1) + 1/n)}{n^2}$$